# FastCourier API - Invalid ip accessing app

Tags: ip

I'm trying to work out a call to FastCourier API https://enterprise.fastcourier.com.au/docs/api to get a simple quote but it keeps throwing me the error "Invalid ip accessing app" when it's set to the server IP on my https://enterprise.fastcourier.com.au/account/developer-settings.

```
$apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
$url2 = 'https://enterprise-api.fastcourier.com.au/api/quotes';

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL, $url2);

// Create an associative array containing the POST data
$post_data = array(
    "quote" => array(
        "dropoff_postcode" => "2259",
        "dropoff_state" => "NSW",
        "dropoff_suburb" => "TUGGERAWONG",
        "parcel_attributes" => array(
            "qty" => "1",
            "weight" => "10.6")
    )
);  

$data = http_build_query($post_data) . "\n";
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Secret-Key: ' . $apiKey .' '
));  


curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json_response = curl_exec($ch2);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch2);

if ($curl_errno > 0) {
                echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
        } else {
               print_r(json_decode($json_response, true));
        }

curl_close($ch2);

// IP address of the server 
$ip_server = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; 
echo "<br>Server IP Address is: $ip_server";
```

Any help welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is provided by AskSia!

```php
// Initialize a cURL session
$ch2 = curl_init();
// Set the URL option for a cURL transfer
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL, $url2);

// Create an associative array containing the POST data
$post_data = array(
  "pickupSuburb" => "TUGGERAWONG",
  "pickupState" => "NSW",
  "pickupPostcode" => "2259",
  "pickupBuildingType" => "residential",
  "isPickupTailLift" => false,
  "destinationSuburb" => "MELBOURNE",
  "destinationState" => "VIC",
  "destinationPostcode" => "3000",
  "destinationBuildingType" => "residential",
  "isDropOffTailLift" => false,
  "isDropOffPOBox" => false,
    "items" => array(
        "type" => "box",
        "weight" => "10.6",
        "length" => "25",
        "width" => "23",
        "height" => "20",
        "quantity" => "1"
    )
); 

// Encode the array into a JSON formatted string
$data = json_encode($post_data);

// Set the HTTPHEADER option for a cURL session
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Secret-Key: ' . $apiKey
));  

// Set the custom request type to POST
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
// Set the POST fields for the cURL session
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
// Set the option to return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Execute the cURL session and store the response
$json_response = curl_exec($ch2);
// Check for cURL errors
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch2);

// Handle cURL errors if any
if ($curl_errno > 0) {
                // Output the error message
                echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
        } else {
                // Decode the JSON response and print it
               print_r(json_decode($json_response, true));
        }

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch2);

// Get the server IP address
$ip_server = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; 
// Output the server IP address
echo "<br>Server IP Address is: $ip_server";
```

The provided code initializes a cURL session, sets various options including the URL, HTTP headers, and POST fields, executes the cURL request, and then handles the response or errors. It also retrieves and displays the server's IP address.

Step-by-step Instruction

- Initialize a cURL session using `curl_init()`.
- Set the URL for the cURL session using `curl_setopt()` with the `CURLOPT_URL` option.
- Create an associative array with the required POST data.
- Encode the POST data array into a JSON formatted string using `json_encode()`.
- Set the HTTP headers for the cURL session using `curl_setopt()` with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.
- Set the request type to POST using `curl_setopt()` with the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option.
- Set the POST fields for the cURL session using `curl_setopt()` with the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.
- Set the option to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` using `curl_setopt()` with the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.
- Execute the cURL session using `curl_exec()` and handle the response or errors.
- Close the cURL session using `curl_close()`.
- Retrieve and display the server's IP address using the `$_SERVER` superglobal array.